# How would I express this Portuguese idiom about telling secrets?

Tags: translation, idiom-request

I'm trying to translate a title of a book, it's an expression that if translated literally would produce this:

> Now [I] already told [you]

This does not look like it's giving the same idea of the original title (in Portuguese: "Agora já contei").

The original title gives the idea of "telling something, briefly, maybe a secret, without the initial consent of the teller", like "oops, now I already told you".

Is there any expression close to that idea?

Comment: Are you looking for idioms like [spilled the beans](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans) or [cat's out of the bag](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+the+cat+out+of+the+bag)?  Are you looking for informal phrasings like [let it slip](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+slip) or [loose lips](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Loose+Lips+Sink+Ships)?

Comment: @NickeManarin "A Slip of the Tongue."

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan `Let it slip` :D That's a perfect fit. Thanks.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan, would you please post your suggestions as an answer so we can close this question (and so I can upvote your answer)? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for idioms like [spilled the beans](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans) or [cat's out of the bag](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+the+cat+out+of+the+bag)?    Are you looking for informal phrasings like [let it slip](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+slip) or [loose lips](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Loose+Lips+Sink+Ships)?